# expected point is not right in epipolar geometry

Tags: matlab, geometry, computer-vision, projection, perspectivecamera

I have 2 cameras (camera 2 is translating respect camera 1) with their projection matrix **P1** and **P2**. They took an image, **I1** (camera 1) and **I2** (camera 2) 512x512.

```
P1 =

-510.0686  -12.9401 -259.3765 -130.4363
-7.6701 -517.0217 -257.2912  -66.5024
-0.0325   -0.0518   -1.0108   -0.4847


P2 =

-736.7330  -13.5206 -388.4970 -828.1644
-12.1721 -749.3048 -375.2760 -560.6533
-0.0291   -0.0623   -1.4690   -3.2141
```

I compute the fundamental matrix F:

```
F =

1.0e+003 *

0.0000    0.0033   -0.6047
-0.0033    0.0000    0.7938
0.5973   -0.8252    5.9205
```

Then I found matches point between two images with SURF using RANSAC, **point1** and **point2**.

```
point1 =

235.3386
135.3108
1.0000

point2 =

242.7049
133.9451
1.0000
```

I tried to compute epipolar line and it passing through the point2

```
epLineCam2 = F * punto1;

epLineCam2 =

1.0e+004 *

-0.0158
0.0028
3.4824
```

So **point2** should be quite similar to the expected point **epoint** in I2, computed using epipolar geometry (because SURF uses a lot of approximations).

As you can see on 8.2 pag. 223 on [Hartley & Zisserman's book](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf),

```
x' = Hπ * x;
```

where x' is the *epoint*, and x is *point1*.

my *Hπ* is:

```
Hpi = P2 * pinv(P1); 

Hpi =

1.4397   -0.1502  296.2940
-0.0008    1.3476  206.4950
-0.0001   -0.0006    2.5772
```

So *epoint* is:

```
epoint =

614.7787
388.6410
2.4873
```

I reme,ber you that image size is 512x512, so *epoint.x* is outside of image...
As you can see, epoint is different (a lot different) by point2

```
point2 =

242.7049
133.9451
1.0000
```

My question is, **why? Where I made some mistakes?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted any matlab code it is hard to tell where exactly you made mistakes, but there are a few suggestions I can make to you:

For one, the matched points found by SURF do not necessary have to be correct points. Have you checked whether `point1` actually matches `point2`, by just drawing them onto the images for instance?

Furthermore, I do know how you obtained your projection matrices, but if they were correct the following condition should indeed hold:

```
x' = P2 * pinv(P1) * x
```

You could verify easily if your projection matrices are correct by drawing both x and x' and see if they're matching points. Note that x' and x are [Homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). This note also gives you an idea of why `epoint` is so much different than `point2`. If you divide the vector epoint by its z-coordinate you will get a result which is more similar to point2:

```
         614.7787     247.1671
epoint = 388.6410  =  156.2502
         2.4873       1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks! The "problem" was that i didn't understand Homogeneous coordinates! As you said, if I divide my vector by its z-coordinate, epoint is quite similiar to point2!
You save me :)
I'm sure datas are right, I plotted them onto the images.

Comment: @RobertoIacono Could you mark this question as solved, such that other people don't waste their time on a question that has already been solved? :)